# Optimising selective joins from multiple tables using a lookup

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a (SQL Server) table as follows, where each row can either only have zero or one Y and represents which version of data is required when building a final combined table.

LOOKUP

| ID (PK) | FromV1 | FromV2 | FromV3 | FromV4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Town1 | Y | N | N | N |
| Town2 | N | Y | N | N |
| Town3 | N | N | N | N |

i.e. this could easily be an enum (an int representing v1,v2,v3,v4 or none) if it turns out it could be faster...

| ID (PK) | FromVersion |
| --- | --- |
| Town1 | 1 |
| Town2 | 2 |
| Town3 | 0 |

This lookup table is built by another process early on in production, ID is the unique key.

Tables FromV1, V2, V3, V4 contain the actual data for all towns holding millions of rows, i.e. each version is the same structure and each contains rows for the same towns:

- TOWN1,field1,field2...
- TOWN1,field1,field2...
- TOWN2, field1,field2...

So, what happens is I create a new 'final' table that contains all the town data from the relevant source tables where the flag was set, e.g.

```
Insert into FINAL Select t.* from TABLEV1 t Join LOOKUP u on t.ID=u.ID and u.FromV1='Y'
Insert into FINAL Select t.* from TABLEV2 t Join LOOKUP u on t.ID=u.ID and u.FromV2='Y'
Insert into FINAL Select t.* from TABLEV3 t Join LOOKUP u on t.ID=u.ID and u.Fromv3='Y'
Insert into FINAL Select t.* from TABLEV4 t Join LOOKUP u on t.ID=u.ID and u.Fromv4='Y'
```

Or using the enum variant, it would be "AND u.enum=1", "AND u.enum=2", etc if that would optimise things.

I'd like to improve performance, is the following any faster or is there a better way?

One way I thought might improve speed due to guaranteeing the sort order of all the required rows, but don't know if it will yield better results, is instead of creating the one LOOKUP table, I create one for each version, e.g. LOOKUPV1, LOOKUPV2.

Then the index on the Y/N/enum will order the data so the clustered scan/seek would be increased slightly as the flag data is sorted and we know we're grabbing every row? e.g.

```
Insert into FINAL Select t.* from TABLEV1 t Join LOOKUPV1 u on t.ID=u.ID and u.flag='Y'
Insert into FINAL Select t.* from TABLEV2 t Join LOOKUPV2 u on t.ID=u.ID and u.flag='Y'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `IN`:

```
Insert into FINAL
    Select t.*
    from TABLEV1 t Join
         LOOKUP u
         on t.ID = u.ID and 'Y' IN (u.FromV1, u.FromV2, u.FromV3, u.FromV4);
```

You mention enums in your question.  SQL Server does not support enums.

Comment: When I say enum, I mean 'enum' in the sense of using an int to represent each so 1=v1, 2=v2, etc. However, I think you misinterpreted my (long) question, there will always be 4 tables to get from, TABLEV1, TABLEV2, etc. and each flag simply represents where to get it from, so FromV1 with a Y means insert data from TABLEV1 for that town, fromV2 with a Y means insert data from TABLEV2, etc.

Comment: @Neil . . . You may not be aware, but some databases -- such as MySQL and Postgres -- do support `enum`s as a type.